# How can I get access to a fragment method from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which summons a custom CursorAdaper and display it on a ListView
. The thing is I want to change the cursor by `changeCursor()` from another activity when I add new data, How can I get access to the CursorAdapter displayed on the fragment?

Comment: I suggest you move the method that creates the CursorAdapter to another class so you can use it from different parts. [You should separate classes that fetch and manipulate data from the classes that show it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: @m0skit0 the method that creates the CursorAdapter is actually on another class but someone has edited my question and changed the meaning so my Fragment summons the CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have to pass data from one Activity to another and let the fragment of you choice receive the data (each fragment of a given Activity may get the Intent that started/restarted/resumed the Activity).

Consider this code

-- pass data:

```
String[] myListEntries = getNewListContents();
Intent updateList = new Intent(this, ActivityThatListFragmentBelongsTo.class);
updateList.putExtra("updated_list", myListEntries);
startActivity(updateList);
```

-- receive data (in fragment):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  Intent wasStartedWithData = getActivity().getIntent();
  String[] updatedList = wasStartedWithData.getStringArrayExtra("updated_list");
  // pass updatedList to adapter
}
```

Now you might actually have more complicated data than an Array of Strings. In this case 
you could create a class that implements 'Parcelable' (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and call
putExtra(Parcelable parcel) / getParcelableExtra(String name) on the Intent.

Comment: I'm actually using ViewPager. And I do not wanna launch the fragment I just wanna refresh the listView to get the new data from my local Mysql Database.

Comment: You said, you want to update your content from another Activity. Therefore I assume you have 2 Activities A and B. A hosts a ViewPager that in turn hosts fragments. B is an Activity that may be started (probably from one of the fragments inside the ViewPager) to perform some operation and then update the content of the fragment of the Viewpager of A accordingly. If B is started by A or one of it's fragments, then you can use startActivityForResult() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)). Otherwise, see my answer.

Comment: Exactly so where do I post the onActivityResult method? Fragment doens't seem to recognize it. And if I post it on Activity A I couldn't get access to the fragment's listView and CursorAdapter.

Comment: You can use another Intent from onActivityResult. I know you won't believe me. But my initial answer was right all along. If you call startActivity and the corresponding Activity is already running you don't restart it, but just deliver the Intent. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)